# edit button in jquery to change static date cells in an html table into text box/calender

Tags: jquery, button, edit

Here is my HTML table transformed to jquery. I want an edit button that when clicked, changes the start and expire cells to datepickers and makes them editable. Any suggestions?

```
$.each(data, function(idx, val) {
    strHTML = '<tr id="tr1">'
    strHTML = strHTML + '<td><input type="button" class="deleteButton" id="delBut" value="delete"/></td>'
    strHTML = strHTML + '<td><a><div class="foreman">' + val.ABALPH + '</div></a></td>'
    strHTML = strHTML + '<td contentEditable><a><div class="start">' + val.StartDate + '</div></a></td>'
    strHTML = strHTML + '<td contentEditable><a><div class="expire">' + val.EndDate + '</div></a></td>'
    strHTML = strHTML + '<td><input type="button" class="editButton" id="editBut" value="edit" data-mini="true"/><div class="edit"></div></td>'
    strHTML = strHTML + '<td><div class="NOTES"></div></td>'
    strHTML = strHTML + '</tr>'

    var currRow = strHTML;
    $(currRow).appendTo($('#foremanTable'));
})
```

Comment: do you want to convert simple text input to calendar input?

Comment: calender input but if I know how to do the simple text then I could figure out the calender I believe